# Distance function is continuous on $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n$ and Interior set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> (1) Consider $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual Euclidean metric. The *interior* of a set $C$, denoted $C^o$, is the set of points $x$ such that there exists an $r>0$ with $B(x,r)\subset C$.
>
> > (a) Let $n=1$. What is the interior of $[a,b]$?
> >
> > (b) Prove that if $U$ is open and $C\subset U$ is compact, then there is a compact set $D$ such that $C\subset D^o$ and $D\subset U$. [Hint: first consider $C=[a,b]$ in $\Bbb R%$, then generalize.]
>
> (2) Let $d(x,y)$ be the Euclidean metric in $\Bbb R^n$.
>
> > (a) Prove $d(x,y)$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n.$
> >
> > (b) Let $C$ be a **non-empty** closed set in $\Bbb R^n$, and $y\in \Bbb R^n$. Prove that there is a point in $C$ closest to $y$, *i.e.* there is a $z\in C$ such that $d(y,z)\le d(y,x)$ for all $x\in C.$

I'm a beginner. I want to know a little instructions to solve :)  THX

Comment: Yes , thx , how can I type that?

Comment: Please do not force us to go offsite to read your question.

Comment: I try to type now

Comment: I have edited your question so that it is self-contained and properly formatted. Also, I fixed an error in the first question by changing $\epsilon$ to $r$, and added a necessary condition to the second question (seen in bold). Press the [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/362681/edit) button to see how I typeset things. In the future, please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Fine. Now where did you get stuck? No idea for 1.a? For 2.a you might generalize to showing that the metric  $d\colon X\times X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous for any metric space (but 2.b does not work for arbitrary metric spaces!)

Comment: How do you define "compact"? Knowing which definition(s) of compactness you're working with will make it easier for us to answer question (1)(b).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.a:
You may already suspect that the interior is $(a,b)$. Can you specify a ball $B(x,r)\subset [a,b]$ if you are given $x$ with $a<x<b$? Why is $B(a,r)$ (or $B(b,r)$) not a subset of $[a,b]$, no matter how small $r$ is?

1.b:
For every point $x\in C$ there is an open ball $B(x,r_x)\subseteq U$ because $x\in U$ and $U$ is open.
Then $C$ is contained in the union of all $B(x,\frac12r_x)$ (why do I switch to half the radius?). 
Since $C$ is compact, a finite union $\bigcup_{i=1}^n{B(x_i,\frac12 r_{x_i})} $suffices. The union of the *closures* of these *finitely* many balls, 
$$D:=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\overline{B(x_i,\frac12 r_{x_i})}$$
is compact (why?), contains $C$ in its interior (why?) and is contained in $U$ (why?).

2.a. This is a little exercise in the triangle inequality. Write down explicitly, what it means to be continuous.

2.b. if $c\in C$ (such a point exists thanks to Cameron's correction of the statement) we can replace $C$ with $C\cap\overline{B(y,d(y,c))}$. This is a compact set (why?) and therefore the continuous function $x\mapsto d(x,y)$ assumes its minimum on it. This is also the minimum for all of $C$ (why?).

Comment: @Hegen von Eitzen, Could yo explain me all your questions in the pont 1.b? i have tried to figured them out but i am stocked. Thank you¡